# how to add div value to a variable via jquery

Tags: jquery

So i have a div which is text area. Now I want to take the text generated here and store it to a variable. how do i do that in jquery.

this is my code. i want to use a flag to store one value and then later concatenate it to other value and display.

```
jQuery("#analysis_selectbox").change(function () {
    Flag = text_area.val

    if (jQuery(this).val() == "1") {
        jQuery("#text_area").val(Flag + "success1");
    } else {
        jQuery("#text_area").val(Flag + "success2");

    }
});
});
```

Comment: `Flag = text_area.val` -> `Flag = jQuery("#text_area").val()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2mjdfgck/1/

Comment: Kindly provide your HTML code

Comment: it worked  :) thanks a lot @arun p johny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to use `jQuery("#text_area").val()` or `jQuery("#text_area")[0].value` , because `val` is neither a valid jQuery or JavaScript selector

```
jQuery("#analysis_selectbox").change(function(){
    Flag = jQuery("#text_area").val();

    if (jQuery(this).val() == "1") 
    {
    jQuery("#text_area").val(Flag + "success1");
    }
    else {
    jQuery("#text_area").val(Flag + "success2");  

    }
});
```